# How can I set shutter speed and iso settings in sony DSC qx10 lens style camera?

Tags: camera, iso, sony, remoteapi

I have created a sample application and I am getting list of available apis from camera which include only getSupportedIsoSpeedRateand not setIsoSpeedRate,getAvailableIsoSpeedRate,getIsoSpeedRate. And when I send request for setIsoSpeedRate I am getting an error, Can you tell me how will I access setIsoSpeedRate with as the documentation provided in Sony developer's website. I am using DSC-QX10 Lens style camera. And I am getting the below mentioned error when I am trying to send Json request for any method which is not available in device's available API list .

My Request Json is

```
{"id":11,"method":"setIsoSpeedRate","version":"1.0","params":["800"]}
```

and I am getting this response from server device

```
{"error":[1,""],"id":1}
```

Comment: "Getting an error" isn't particularly descriptive of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the API is not listed in the return from the available API list then it is not supported on that device.  So what you are seeing is expected.